# Why would the size of a deque be less than a small number?

Tags: c++, while-loop, deque

I have a program in which I need to make a `deque` long enough to hold an item at a certain index. I use the following loop to expand the `deque`:

```
while(int1+deque1.size()<=int2){
     deque1.push_back(0);
}
```

When both `int1` and `int2` are `-1` (and in many other situations; this is one I noticed while debugging), `deque1` grows to a monstrous size (hundreds of thousands of items), but the loop keeps going. Why is this?

Comment: `deque1.size()` returns a value of an unsigned type

Comment: By the way, `std::deque` has a `resize()` function.

Comment: Why wouldn't adding an int change it to become signed? (I turned on wanrings and the unsigned-signed comparison was indeed the problem.)

Comment: Unsigned types, sigh. Whoever thought they were a good idea.

Comment: @JakobWeisblat, Because signed integers are promoted to unsigned integers.

Comment: `I have a program in which I need to make a deque long enough to hold an item at a certain index.` Are you sure?

Comment: @chris I will use that since it is probably more efficient.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I was about to address that :p Something like a map might be more preferable.

Comment: I am not sure what the final length will be, but *most* of the slots will be filled up to it. Once I know the final length, I resize it and add the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deque::size() returns an unsigned long int, therefore int1 and int2 MUST be positive numbers, otherwise you'll get an overflow.

This is the code that the compiler automatically produces.

```
while(static_cast<unsigned long>(int1)+deque1.size()<=static_cast<unsigned long>(int2)){
 deque1.push_back(0);
}
```

so if (for example) int1 is an 8 bit unsigned integer, and you give it the value -1, it will become (2^8 - 1 = 255). That's how bit encoding works in computers.

The solution is probably the following:

```
while(int1+static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(deque1.size())<=int2){
 deque1.push_back(0);
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: `long` is a bad idea, I fixed it for you.

Comment: @Mehrdad could you please explain why?

Comment: Because it isn't likely to be large enough to avoid data loss. On a 64-bit system, `long` can be 32-bit (Visual C++, for example), whereas `ptrdiff_t` is 64-bit. Using `long` would cause truncation and cause you to get invalid answers. `ptrdiff_t` is the best alternative because it must be able to represent `distance(begin, end)`, which is the size.